# Need help getting log cleanup script to acknowledge multiple conditions

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a log clean up script to cleanup IIS logs. However I have a criteria that I need the script to fulfill. I need the script to skip folders that only have 1 log file regardless of its age and delete all logs older than 31 days. I'm not the most experienced person with Powershell but every time I get the script to run. I can have it skip folders with 1 log file present but it will ignore my 31 day criteria. When I get it to acknowledge the 31 day criteria, it then ignores the skip folders with 1 log file present and wipes it out.

Any help would be appreciated!!

```bsh
$folders = Get-ChildItem c:\inetpub\logs\TestingEnvironment -Recurse -Directory
if ($folder -eq $folders.FullName) {
    Write-Host "Clearing in $folder"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Filter '*.log' |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        Remove-Item
    Get-ChildItem –Path C:\inetpub\logs\TestingEnvironment -Recurse |
        Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)) }
}
```

I expect the script to give preserve folders with only 1 log present regardless of their age and clean out folders that have multiple logs older than 31 days out.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)
Get-ChildItem 'c:\inetpub\logs\TestingEnvironment' -Recurse -Filter '*.log' -File | 
    Group-Object DirectoryName | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Group  | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
```

Check if the console output is what you expect. If this is OK, then remove the `-WhatIf` switch to actually have the files removed.

**Update**

If you want just one (the latest) file to remain, the code would look like

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)
Get-ChildItem 'c:\inetpub\logs\TestingEnvironment' -Recurse -Filter '*.log' -File | 
    Group-Object DirectoryName | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Group  | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
        Remove-Item -WhatIf
    }
```

**Update 2**

If, as you commented, you would like the script to write out a text file with all filenames the script deletes, change it to this:

```
$dateNow    = Get-Date
$refDate    = $dateNow.AddDays(-31)
$outputFile = 'D:\Results.txt'

Get-ChildItem 'c:\inetpub\logs\TestingEnvironment' -Recurse -Filter '*.log' -File | 
    Group-Object DirectoryName | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
        ForEach-Object { 
            '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {1}' -f $dateNow, $_.FullName | Add-Content -Path $outputFile
            $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

Comment: That did significantly help. However, some folders that only have multiple logs that are older than 31 days are being wiped out. I need one to still be preserved.

Comment: @bmaz1093 Although in your question you said to delete _all logs older than 31 days_, I have updated the answer to keep the latest one and delete all others.

Comment: My mistake for not being more clear. This seems to have done it! Tomorrow I will get around to testing it further and will report back. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Ok, so the script performs as I need it to. How would I go about making it create a .txt file listing everything that was deleted? I can get it to create a "Results.txt" file but the document is blank.

Comment: @bmaz1093 See Update 2 of my answer. It now writes out a textfile with the full names of the files that are deleted.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate it! I apparently need to start doing some powershell lessons.